# How to import commerce products along with inline entities by using drupal commerce feeds?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce, drupal-feeds

I need to import set of drupal commerce products with CSV file and this particular product type contain inline entity form. So I need to upload and create list of products along with their corresponding nodes (inline entity reference). Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the "Documentation" section at the bottom of [Commerce feeds](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) module page.

> Please watch this amazing screencast and step by step by rfay about
>   how to set up and use commerce feeds:

[Importing Products using Feeds](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/467)